# Is there a way to specify ES6 generator method in object literal in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iterator, ecmascript-6

I cannot seem to create a generator method as object literal.

Here is my working source code:

```
function *getRecords (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        yield data[i];
    }
}
var records = getRecords(data);
for (var record of records) {
   // process my record
}
```

But the when I move my generator method in object literal:

```
var myobj = {
    *getRecords: function (data) {...}
}
```

I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token *`

If I add quotes

```
var myobj = {
    '*getRecords': function (data) {...}
}
```

I get: `SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word`

I'm runnng nodejs v0.12.2 with `--harmony` option, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `*` should be after the `function` keyword, like this

```
var myobj = {
    getRecords: function* (data) {}
}

for (var record of myobj['getRecords']()) {}
```

Quoting the [Draft version of ECMA Script - 6's definition for Generator Expression](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-generator-function-definitions),

> function * ( FormalParameters<sub>[Yield,GeneratorParameter]</sub> ) {
>
> *GeneratorBody*
>
> }

**Note:** Generator Expression is different from Generator Function. When you assign it to a variable or associate it to a key in Object literal, you are actually assigning a Generator Expression. The normal generator declaration will be like this

```
function * GeneratorFunctionName(...) {
}
```

Comment: How to make generator in the `class {}` syntax? There is no `function` keyword in that syntax.

Answer (score 13):

A @thefoureye already answered, if you are using function expressions then you will have to place the `*` token right after the `function` token.

However, you can also use method definitions in object literals. Here, you'd place the `*` before the generator method name indeed, however as with every method definition it does not contain the colon and the `function` keyword:

```
var myobj = {
    *getRecords(data) {
        …
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Here how to do it in plain object definition:

```
var myobj = {
    getRecords: function* (data) {...}
}
```

Here how to do it in ES6 class definition:

```
class MyClass {
    * getRecords(data) {...}
}
var myobj = new MyClass();
```