# How to create an iterator within a class

Tags: javascript, iterator, ecmascript-6

For a ES2015 js class I would like to have an iterator. So I tried the following

```
export default class MyList {
    iterator* () {
        // Dummy implementation
        let counter = 0;
        while(true) {
            yield counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Because I would like to do

```
let list = new MyList();
    iter = list.iterator();

while(!iter.done()) { ... }
```

For example.

However, this doesn't work. So the question is, what is the preferred way to implement an iterator inside a class ?

Comment: related: [Is there a way to specify ES6 generator method in object literal in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29750429/1048572)

Comment: *"However, this doesn't work"* is a very poor problem description. Based on the accepted answer, you should have gotten a syntax error. This is important information!

Comment: The error is `SyntaxError: missing : after property id` which is informative for those who have dealt with the language for some time but not for a newcomer, especially because colon notation is avoided in favor of the shortened object method notation. Just my 3 cents.

Comment: I expected the title to say it all, which is why I omitted some details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The '*' should be before function name. Like this:

```
export default class MyList {
    *iterator() {
        // Dummy implementation
        let counter = 0;
        while(true) {
            yield counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

You're welcome.